# How to calculate age based on PESEL number in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, math, aggregation

In my country we have PESEL number which consists of 11 numbers.

- First two numbers means year of birth for example: 00 (means 2000), 95 (means 1995) and so on...
- Next two numbers means month.
- Next two numbers means day.

It looks like that: 95050611475, so in this case:

- year is: 1995
- month is: 05
- day is: 06

I have column with PESEL numbers like below:

[image]

And how can I calculate age based on PESEL number and current date ?

**Be aware that if someone has 00 at the beginning of PESEL it means that he born at 2000 year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the substring from `PESEL` and convert it to `datetime`. Then, you can `subtract` it from the `current timestamp`. This will give you the `time delta` in `days`.

If you want to convert this information to `year` you can divide the result with `np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')`.

```
df['age'] = (pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.to_datetime(df.PESEL.str[:6], format = '%y%m%d')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

```
         PESEL        age
0  95050611475  26.093457
1  00112575862  20.535506
```